# What's the difference between file attributes returned by Cocoa and CoreFoundation?

Tags: cocoa, filesystems, macos-carbon

In Cocoa, you can get the attributes of a file as follow

```
NSString *path = @"/path/to/some/file";
NSError *err = ......;
NSDictionary *dic = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:&err];
NSLog(@"%@", dic);
```

And it will return a directory of keys, for example

```
{
    NSFileCreationDate = "2009-12-02 10:03:38 +0000";
    NSFileExtensionHidden = 0;
    NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID = 80;
    NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName = admin;
    NSFileHFSCreatorCode = 0;
    NSFileHFSTypeCode = 0;
    NSFileModificationDate = "2009-12-02 19:20:54 +0000";
    NSFileOwnerAccountID = 501;
    NSFileOwnerAccountName = Tony;
    NSFilePosixPermissions = 511;
    NSFileReferenceCount = 1;
    NSFileSize = 496988;
    NSFileSystemFileNumber = 5187496;
    NSFileSystemNumber = 234881029;
    NSFileType = NSFileTypeRegular;
}
```

Now, you can also use the `CoreFoundation` `MDItem` to get file attributes

```
NSString *path = @"/path/to/some/file";
MDItemRef mdItem = MDItemCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)path);
CFArrayRef arr = MDItemCopyAttributeNames(mdItem);
CFDictionaryRef dic = MDItemCopyAttributes(mdItem, arr);
NSLog(@"%@", dic);
```

And it will return something like this

```
{
    kMDItemAuthors =     (
        "Some One"
    );
    kMDItemContentCreationDate = "2009-12-02 10:03:38 +0000";
    kMDItemContentModificationDate = "2009-12-02 19:20:54 +0000";
    kMDItemContentType = "org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation";
    kMDItemContentTypeTree =     (
        "org.openxmlformats.presentationml.presentation",
        "org.openxmlformats.openxml",
        "public.zip-archive",
        "com.pkware.zip-archive",
        "public.data",
        "public.item",
        "com.apple.bom-archive",
        "public.archive",
        "public.presentation",
        "public.composite-content",
        "public.content"
    );
    kMDItemDateAdded = "2011-08-16 07:52:53 +0000";
    kMDItemDisplayName = "Some File.pptx";
    kMDItemFSContentChangeDate = "2009-12-02 19:20:54 +0000";
    kMDItemFSCreationDate = "2009-12-02 10:03:38 +0000";
    kMDItemFSCreatorCode = 0;
    kMDItemFSFinderFlags = 0;
    kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon = 0;
    kMDItemFSInvisible = 0;
    kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden = 0;
    kMDItemFSIsStationery = 0;
    kMDItemFSLabel = 0;
    kMDItemFSName = "Some File.pptx";
    kMDItemFSNodeCount = 496988;
    kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID = 80;
    kMDItemFSOwnerUserID = 501;
    kMDItemFSSize = 496988;
    kMDItemFSTypeCode = 0;
    kMDItemKind = "Microsoft PowerPoint presentation";
    kMDItemLogicalSize = 496988;
    kMDItemPhysicalSize = 499712;
    kMDItemTitle = "PowerPoint Presentation";
}
```

My question is, what's the difference between these two methods of finding file attributes? There seem to be some equivalence but not all the time, which is better? And why are there these two ways anyways?

Comment: `@"/path/to/some/file"` is a path, not a URL. For that reason, “`url`” is a bad name for that variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attributes returned from NSFileManager are attributes stored on the file in the filesystem. The results from MDItemCopyAttributes are from the Spotlight index which includes most (all?) of the filesystem attributes as well as the results from any of the Spotlight plugins installed on the system.

Comment: One thing relevant to this is that Spotlight can be turned off, either per-volume or system-wide. If the user has turned it off for the relevant volume and/or generally, then there is no Spotlight index to consult, so the Metadata APIs will return nothing. NSFileManager, Core Services File Manager, and `stat` and friends work regardless of whether Spotlight is enabled.

Comment: Also, NSFileManager option gives you precise information when file is modified (either by user or system) than MDItem which updates its attributes values after one or two minute delay.